# What else adds order comments?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, security

I have a task to add a WYSIWYG editor on the admin order comments.
So far so good. I was able to make it work.
But I have a concern. By default order comments are escaped when listed and only a few tags are allowed on the backend.

```
echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(), array('b','br','strong','i','u')); //backend
echo $this->escapeHtml($_historyItem->getComment());  //frontend
```

Also when sending the e-mail all tags are stripped.

```
$comment = trim(strip_tags($data['comment']));
```

I changed that to allow all HTML tags and it seams to work just fine, but who else writes these comments?

What I know so far is:

1. The admins, manually - and I trust them
2. Online payment methods when sending a payment update - and I trust them.

Should I look at something else?

**[EDIT]**
I realized from the comments below that I may have not made this clear.
Everything seams to work ok, I don't have comments appearing out of nowhere, I'm just concerned if this is a good practice or should I be careful of something else that might post order comments.

Comment: Do you have anywhere in your site where the customer can add comments to orders?

Comment: @jharrison.au Oh. I realize from your comment that maybe I asked the question wrong. I don't have comments appearing out of nowhere. I'm just concerned if what I did is a good idea or there are security issues with it. The website is a standard magento 1.7 with some extensions, but none of them touch the orders. Maybe the Ogone payment but that one I trust.

Comment: yes I understood, just making sure that users can't generate comments as well. I can't think of anything else that would be creating order comments, I would go for it

Comment: To expand on @jharrison.au: if I as a customer can generate an order comment in checkout or customer account order view, then I can attack your backend.

Comment: @Melvyn. please don't attack my backend :)). No The customers can't write comments on their orders. Not even gift messages.

Comment: Not even a "please ship on friday" in the checkout?

Comment: @Melvyn. Nope. Just table rate shipping costs and an external shipping carrier that has its own shipping policy. So the customer does not get a saying about when the order will be shipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in doubt about 3rd party comments, why not just wrap the method in a conditional statement.

Assuming that only your admin users need access to WYSIWIG/HTML comment support, then you could ensure it is only enabled for such. For API based comments (eg. Payment gateway notifications), then escape the HTML as normal.

I wouldn't trust any 3rd party to have unescaped HTML control over the comments (why expose the risk?).

It seems simple, trust no-one but your admin staff, only permit unescaped comments from those entering them via the admin (not via API).

Comment: Doh! I feel all Homer Simpson about this. Of course this is the obvious thing to do. And I implemented it this way, partially.To my surprise only the admin comments are not escaped when adding them in the way I implemented this. The only thing that is missing is differentiating between comments from admins and other ones for displaying them on frontend (escaped or raw). And I can just add a flag on the `sales_flat_order_status_history` table to make the difference. Thanks!.